# object file not PIC showing relocatable?

Tags: linux, gcc, fpic

I have a small library, and I build it with `gcc` without `-fPIC` option, I think this would mean that the generated object file will not be relocatable, but when I issued `file` command, it shows relocatable, why?

build command:

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -g -o module.o -c module.c
file module.o


module.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looking at the object file, before it is linked into a binary. ELF files are generally one of four types:

CORE core files

DYN Shared object file, for libraries

EXEC Executable file, for binaries

REL Relocatable file, before linked into an executable file

See [this link for more info](https://linux-audit.com/elf-binaries-on-linux-understanding-and-analysis/)

Comment: ..and if you think about it, an object file is relocatable until its been linked.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the difference between position `independent` and `relocatable`. Position `independent` shared `libraries` have relative addresses and can work anywhere in the virtual memory WITHOUT modification of the text segment. However, `relocatable` shared libraries have `absolute` addresses, so their text segment is modified every time they are loaded into `RAM`.